# How to get empty test folder into Jenkins Workspace?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, jenkins, testing, jenkins-pipeline

I have a java class for which I wrote a test that requires an empty folder within src/test/resources.
This test runs fine, but within my Jenkins Workspace it fails, because that empty folder does not make it to the Jenkins Workspace. Apparently it gets filtered somewhere along the way; some configuration seems to suggest that empty folders may be ignored.

How can I make sure the empty folder shows up in my Jenkins workspace? It is a basic spring boot project that is built with maven.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the problem lay with git not tracking empty folders.

So I used a different approach for my test utilising @TempDir instead of an empty folder within src/test/resources.